# Repeat alarm in specific day using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was creating an alarm clock using HTML, jQuery and JavaScript. I have some problems with the repeating of the alarm: I want it to repeat according to the day that the user has chosen, like when you want to repeat every Monday only, but I don't know how to start it.

Comment: You cannot do this just by client side. You will have to use server side language. Save selected day and then on page load, call server and get `alarmDetails` and process accoudingly

Comment: Also, you should share some code that you have tried and achieved so far.

Comment: @Rajesh it's possible, should `detect` day with `jquery`